# Correlated time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, statistical-significance

I am trying to solve a problem involving calibration of environmental instrumentation. I have two instruments set up side-by-side, measuring essentially the same condition. There will be a certain degree of randomness in the difference between the two time series, but they will exhibit a very high correlation. The two instruments may have drifted since they were last calibrated and I am wanting to decide if this difference is significant at some pre-determined level. What would be the best statistic for this?

Comment: Is statistical significance really relevant to the problems of calibration?  Ordinarily your concern would be to *characterize* and *estimate*, as well as possible, the drift between the two instruments so that ultimately you could correct the values of one to be comparable to those of the other.

Comment: Thanks. The problem comes from a commonly employed technique of temporarily deploying a recently calibrated instrument alongside another that is part of a regular monitoring station. The results are then compared to decide if the regular instrument needs replacement or not. Currently there is no statistically robust basis for making this decision.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  In principle, if you run the instruments in parallel long enough, you always will find a "significant" difference, no matter how tiny.  It might be more relevant to ask a slightly different question: *is there a difference that is large enough to matter?*

Comment: Indeed. That is exactly what I am looking to answer. In practice, the two instruments get run in parallel for one to a few days, so the time series would be about 1000 to 5000 samples, depending on sampling frequency.